# Nutch 2.3 has an old version of hbase jar in runtime/lib folder

Tags: hadoop, solr, hbase, nutch

Nutch 2.3 has an old version of hbase jar file(hbase-0.94.14.jar) in runtime/lib folder. I have downloaded hbase 0.94.14 but it does not start because of "Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4". I can run Hbase 1.1.2 but jar file does not included.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve it by just replacing jars/bindings. The problem lies with Gora that uses pre-1.0 client that is incompatible with HBase 1.0+ versions. Your options right now are to either update Gora (not just the jars, coding is required), wait for an official update or downgrade your HBase server.

[Related jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-443)

[HBase 1.0+ changes](http://www.slideshare.net/enissoz/meet-hbase-10)